# How to download the VRP?

Tags: switch, huawei

in the `flash:/` directory, there have so many files:

[image]

```
<Z306-LW-A>dir
Directory of flash:/

  Idx  Attr     Size(Byte)  Date        Time       FileName
    0  -rw-          1,419  Dec 12 2009 03:37:09   private-data.txt
    1  -rw-            684  Jul 09 2010 19:49:48   hostkey
    2  -rw-          1,093  Dec 12 2009 03:36:58   vrpcfg.zip
    3  -rw-      8,194,476  Jan 01 2008 00:13:29   S2352_S3352-V100R005C01.cc
    4  -rw-            540  Jul 09 2010 19:49:57   serverkey

14,632 KB total (6,596 KB free)
```

I want to know which is the VRP of this Switch? So I can download it then upload it to an older Switch for updating.

I mean in this Switch I want to download the current VRP software, then use it to updating an older VRP Switch.

---

**EDIT-01**

```
[Z306-LW-A]dis version
Huawei Versatile Routing Platform Software
VRP (R) software, Version 5.70 (S2300 V100R005C01)
Copyright (C) 2003-2010 HUAWEI TECH CO., LTD
Quidway S2352P-EI Routing Switch uptime is 131 weeks, 4 days, 14 hours, 52 minutes

EMFEA 0(Master) : uptime is 131 weeks, 4 days, 14 hours, 51 minutes
128M bytes DDR Memory
16M bytes FLASH
Pcb      Version :  VER B
Basic  BOOTROM  Version :  229 Compiled at Aug 24 2010, 21:59:42
Software Version : VRP (R) Software, Version 5.70 (S2300 V100R005C01)
```

Comment: Please be specific in which brand and model switch you’re asking about.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: Are you even sure that the older switch can use that particular code? you may end up bricking the switch.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

S2352_S3352-V100R005C01.cc is your VRP file.

Where 
V is version number 
R is release number

You can DOWNLOAD it by FTP

vrpcfg.zip is configuration file.